# Expanding Logical Disk on Fujitsu Primergy T150 S7 running Serverview

Tags: raid, migration, megaraid, expansion, serverview

We have a Fujitsu Primergy T150 S7 with an LSI based D2616 RAID controller with a logical drive running on two 146GB SAS drives and RAID 1. We need to expand the logical drive, so we bought two new 600GB drives. We're having some problems with the logical drive expansion as we can't expand from RAID 1 to RAID 1 using ServerView.

According to the ServerView documentation, we can migrate to RAID 0, and then again to RAID 1. However, these seems needlessly complicated and the server is critical with dataloss and (long) downtime not being an option. I also have a fear about ServerView adding the two drives together and expanding the logical disk without me asking it to.

So do we have to migrate to RAID 0 on the current disks, then migrate to RAID 1 on the new disk? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably not relevant anymore since the question is now older than one year.
From what I understood you first need to replace the current 146GB drives with the 600GB ones using either storcli or megacli (since I only have experience with storcli I only posted this commands):

1. Mark the first disk as offline (`storcli /cx[/ex]/sx set offline`)
2. Mark the first disk as missing (`storcli /cx[/ex]/sx set missing`)
3. If the new disk is not already inserted, spindown the old disk, physically replace it with the new one and initialize the new disk.
4. Insert the new disk in to the missing disks array and row (`storcli /cx[/ex]/sx insert array=a row=b`)

All the required information can be found using `storcli /call show` command. The disk group, array and row information are taken from the TOPOLOGY part of the output. See: [this command examples](http://fibrevillage.com/storage/709-storcli-drive-command-examples) for initialize, spinndown and other useful commands.

Check for the automatic rebuild to complete (`storcli /cx[/ex]/sx show rebuild`) and repeat the steps above for the second disk.

As a last step you have to expand the size of the virtual drive with `storcli /cx/vx expand size=<value> [expandarray]`. Check the status with `storcli /cx/vx show expansion`.